Partial Derivative of a Scalar Function
I am working on deriving expressions related to a scalar function $\theta$ defined as $\theta = \cos^{-1} \left( \frac{v_{io}^T}{\|v_{io}\|} \frac{x_{oi}} {\|x_{oi}\|} \right)$, where $v_{io}$ and $x_{io}$ represent vectors related to velocity and position in 3D ($v_{io} = v_i - v_o, x_{oi} = x_o - x_i$).
My goal is to find the first derivative $\dot{\theta}$ and then compute the gradient $ \nabla_{v_i}\dot{\theta}$. I have successfully derived $\dot{\theta}$ as follows:
$\dot{\theta} = \left(\nabla_{x_i} \theta \right)^T \cdot v_i + \left(\nabla_{x_o} \theta \right)^T \cdot v_o$.
Additionally, I have calculated
$\left(\nabla_{x_i} \theta \right)^T = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - z^2}} \left[ \frac{v_{io}^T}{\|v_{io}\|} \left( \frac{I}{\|x_{oi}\|} - \frac{x_{oi} x_{oi}^T}{\|x_{oi}\|^3} \right) \right] $, where $ z = \left( \frac{v_{io}^T}{\|v_{io}\|} \frac{x_{oi}} {\|x_{oi}\|} \right)$.
However, I'm now stuck on finding $\frac{\partial \left( \left(\nabla_{x_i} \theta \right)^T \cdot v_i \right)}{\partial v_i}$.
Could anyone provide a detailed explanation of how to compute this derivative, including any relevant identities or theorems that might assist in the derivation?
Thank you!

can you clarify, how you obtained the first derivative $\dot{\theta}$? Since the derivative of the arccos function is $\frac{d}{dx}{\arccos x} = \dfrac {-1} {\sqrt {1 - x^2} }$ I am surprised not to see any square root expressions. Also it looks very interesting that you are able to describe any changes in time using changes in space via the gradient.

$
\def\bR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\BR#1{\left[#1\right]}
\def\lR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|}
\def\q{\quad}      \def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qif{\q\iff\q} \def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\deriv#1#2{\frac{d #1}{d #2}}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracBR#1#2{\BR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\a{\alpha}  \def\aa{\a^{-1}}  \def\aaa{\a^{-2}}
\def\b{\beta}   \def\bb{\b^{-1}}  \def\bbb{\b^{-2}}
\def\t{\theta}
$Given an arbitrary vector $b,\,$ construct a normalized vector $f\:$
(same direction, unit length)
$$\eqalign{
\b &= \frob b \qiq f &= \bb b \\
}$$
First calculate the differential of the length
$$\eqalign{
\b^2 &= b^Tb &\qiq 2\b\;d\b = 2b^Tdb \\&&\qiq d\b = f^Tdb \\
}$$
and thence the differential of $f$
$$\eqalign{
df &= \bb db \;+\; b\,d\bb \\
 &= \bb db \;-\; b\,\bbb\,\c{d\b} \\
 &= \bb db \;-\; b\,\bbb\c{f^Tdb} \\
 &= \bb\LR{I \;-\; ff^T}db \\
}$$
Now consider a second vector $a$ and its unit vector $e$
$$\eqalign{
\a = \frob a,\q e = \aa a \qiq de=\aa\LR{I-ee^T}da
\\\\
}$$

Consider the dot product of the unit vectors $e\ {\rm and}\ f$
$$\eqalign{
\def\g{\cos(\t)}
\def\s{\sin(\t)}
\cos(\t) \;=\; e^Tf \;=\; f^Te
}$$
and calculate its differential
$$\eqalign{
d\cos(\t) &= e^Tdf \;+\; f^Tde \\
-\s\;d\t
 &= e^T\lR{\bb\LR{I-ff^T}db} \;+\; f^T\lR{\aa\LR{I-ee^T}da} \\
 &= \bb\lR{e-\g\,f}^Tdb \;+\; \aa\lR{f-\g\,e}^Tda \\
d\t &= \fracBR{\g\,f-e}{\b\s}^Tdb \;+\; \fracBR{\g\,e-f}{\a\s}^Tda \\
}$$
From this, one can extract the gradients
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\t}{a} &= \fracLR{\g\,e-f}{\frob a\,\s}, \qq
\grad{\t}{b} &= \fracLR{\g\,f-e}{\frob b\,\s} \\
}$$
and the time derivative
$$\eqalign{
\dot\t &= \fracBR{\g\,f-e}{\frob b\,\s}^T\dot b
    \;+\; \fracBR{\g\,e-f}{\frob a\,\s}^T\dot a
}$$
Update
Differentiating $\dot\t$ is not particularly tricky, merely tedious.
Here's a list of the non-vanishing gradients that you'll need
$$\eqalign{
\grad{a}{a} &= I,
  \qq\grad{\a}{a}=\grad{\frob a}{a}=e,
  \qq\grad{e}{a}=\fracLR{I-ee^T}{\a}
\\
\grad{b}{b} &= I,
  \qq\grad{\b}{b}=\grad{\frob b}{b}=f,
  \qq\grad{f}{b}=\fracLR{I-ff^T}{\b}
\\
&d\g = f^Tde+e^Tdf, \qq d\s = f^Te\;d\t \\
}$$
Perhaps more importantly, the following gradients
are all equal to zero
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\dot a}{a}, \q\grad{\dot b}{a},
 \q\grad{b}{a}, \q\grad{\b}{a}, \q\grad{f}{a},
 \q
\grad{\dot b}{b}, \q\grad{\dot a}{b},
 \q\grad{a}{b}, \q\grad{\a}{b}, \q\grad{e}{b}
}$$
Using the gradients listed above, it is straightforward to calculate
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\dot\t}{a} \q{\sf and}\q \grad{\dot\t}{b}
}$$
